# Custom AtlassianWikiRenderer in JIRA 7.3.x not working

Tags: jira

We have a custom renderer which extends `AtlassianWikiRenderer`. This works fine up to JIRA 7.2.x but starting with JIRA 7.3 (the version with the embedded Rich Text Editor) these kind of renderers suddenly stop working.

The symptom is that the tabs "Text" and "Visual" do not show up anymore while editing fields using the custom renderer.

Has anyone experienced similar trouble?

Answer (score 0):

Atlassian announced that starting from JIRA 7.3.x , Rich Text Editing is their default editor. Maybe you can [disable it](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirasoftware/jira-software-7-3-x-release-notes-861181590.html) and see if you are still seeing similar issue with your extended wikiRenderer or not.

Comment: I could of course do that but that's not intended. IMHO it should work with RTE too. I've opened a ticket at Atlassian Support, thx

Comment: Oh okay. Anyway, if it's a custom renderer you may need to consider incompatibility with newer version of Rich Text Editing as well. I would still check by disabling to see if it's JIRA issue or incompatibility issue :-)